# AngularJS - Can't reload page when clicking the same URL?

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS to build my web app.

```
<nav>
    <a href="/news">news</a>
    <a href="/sport">sport</a>
</nav>
```

When my location is `/news`, then I click `news`, it will not reload the page.

Is there anything I could do to fix it ?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force angular to re-render the current page, you can use:

```
$route.reload();
```

Causes `$route` service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.

Comment: but how can you tell if user clicked the link? do you get a callback where you can put this line?

Comment: Yeah what Omgpop said, where do you place this?